# Instance of 'Model' error while trying collection query from Firebase

Tags: flutter

Hello I'am trying to query of a collection from Firebase.

In my service class, this is query function:

```
Future<List<ReviewModel>> getReviews(String salonUID) async {
    var _ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('bucket')
        .doc('reviewbox')
        .collection('reviews');
    try {
      var _result = await _ref.get();
      List<ReviewModel> reviewList = List.empty(growable: true);

      for (var element in _result.docs) {
          print(element.data()); //print1
        reviewList.add(ReviewModel.fromJson(element.data()));
      }

      print(reviewList); //print2
      return reviewList;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", e.code);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

print1 is returning me this:

```
...
{uid: uid, tarih: 24.3.2022 15:51, rate: 3, comment: comment2, userName: user name2, userID: userID2}
...
```

print2 is returning me this:

```
[Instance of 'ReviewModel', Instance of 'ReviewModel', Instance of 'ReviewModel']
```

Also, I already have 3 documents in Firebase.

How do I handle with print2 problem? I have to achive my model class.

**EDIT**

If I use this in FutureBuilder? How can I achive every field ?
I tried it but I didn't make it.

```
 FutureBuilder<List<ReviewModel>>(
                  future:
                      FakeService().getSalonReviews(controller.salonModel.kUID),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData &&
                        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text(snapshot.data![0].toString());
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text("loading");
                    }
                  },
                )
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problem, what is your desired outcome ?

Comment: What's exactly the problem?

Comment: If I try this  ```print(reviewList);```  It returning me ```Instance of 'ReviewModel'```. I would like to see inside like this [{uid: uid, tarih: 24.3.2022 15:51, rate: 3, comment: comment2, userName: user name2, userID: userID2},]

Comment: I added question in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by reading whatever field you want of the objects. instead of

```
return Text(snapshot.data![0].toString());
```

do

```
return Text(snapshot.data![index].username);
```

or whatever field you want

Answer (score 1):

Use `inspect(reviewList)` instead of `print(reviewList)`.